# Appcmd script that will monitor IIS app pools and send email if application pools is stopped

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, appcmd

I am looking for a script with appcmd, that will monitor the IIS application pools and we can also get email notifications when some apppools are crashed. We want to put the script as a scheduler task.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you combine the information from these two resources

1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771701(v=ws.10).aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/10/18/how-to-get-an-application-pool-configuration-with-appcmd-exe.aspx

But in summary you can use appcmd to return a list of sites which are not in a state of "started";

e.g.

```
appcmd list apppool /state:"Stopped"
```