# Script for checking IIS

Tags: iis-7

Is there a way to check the status of app pools running on IIS using command line?

We have tried to get the status of an app pool by executing a Powershell script but it did not work.

I’m new to IIS. Any inputs would be  really helpful.

Comment: can you show the code that you did try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appcmd script that will monitor IIS app pools and send email if application pools is stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957485/appcmd-script-that-will-monitor-iis-app-pools-and-send-email-if-application-pool)